# Performance impact of Aerospike UDF's?

Tags: user-defined-functions, aerospike, nosql

I would like to know what performance impact I should expect when invoking an UDF (user defined function) written in C everytime some record is created or changed (with the **assumption, that the UDF** code itself **takes no time** - I will optimize that on my own).

Let's say I have hardware capable of running an SSD-persisted namespace on 200k writes/s, can I expect atleast 50k writes/s with the UDF run everytime?

Subquestion: what might limit the UDFs performance (context switching?)

*Reason for asking is that Aerospike is using those UDFs e.g. for Large Data Types, but those are not highly performant according to AS staff (compared to KVS-Ops). My usecase is to use UDFs to keep a broad range of secondary indices within a Redis Cluster up-to-date, allowing for much richer realtime queries (e.g. intersections/unions of 5-10 secondary indices).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best thing is to run the test yourself. Its hard to predict. But I believe that you should be able to do 50k tps.

Mainly the UDF's performance is effected because of the memory allocations that happen under the hood before calling the UDF. If you are using simple datatypes like int/string/blob, then you are better off. If you use list/map in UDF, it will do more memory allocations which will impact the performance.